# Firebase error while syncing a new project on Android Studio (ASCII Error)

Tags: java, android, firebase, gradle, ascii

The problem is that everytime I sync a project on Android Studio (after I followed all the steps on the Firebase guide), the "ASCII" error occured (Note that my `google-services.json` file is already in the `app` folder).

[image: This is the gradle project build file]
[image: And this is the gradle app build file]]
[image: Finally, this is the error]

Comment: I don't think that error is about Firebase at all. Check your project path and see if there are any Non-ASCII characters in it. For example ÖÇŞĞÜ

Comment: if i do not put the lines copied from the firebase guide, the project works.

Comment: @AndreaCominelli Did you find the solution? I'm also facing the same problem.

Comment: unfortunately no... i' trying to use a sort of api by "Msg91.com" but i m not sure how to use it,

Answer (score 0):

After updating the following dependencies. I was able to get rid of this problem

**Project-level build.gradle:**

```
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
```

**App-level build.gradle:**

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.4"
```

Answer (score 0):

Json file for every Android studio is different unless you override over existing project. Make sure that the json file is for that particular project but re adding the project to firebase. Try to use the latest version of Gradle build, and even for the firebase dependencies. Then sync your project an check again because there shouldn't be any error  unless it's an exception error. I am sure you will not have any such error. I also see that build Gradle is highlight because you are using the older version make sure you use the latest version. Also migrate to androidx version of dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

change your Project-level build.gradle: to this 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0